# writing windows service to get the status of another windows service in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I have the below code written in console application and is working fine.

```
                        public void GetData()
                        {
                        ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
                        string strServices = null;
                        foreach (ServiceController service in services)
                        {
                          strServices += service.DisplayName.ToString() + ":" +    service.Status.ToString() + ">";
                        }
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\Info.txt", strServices.Split('>'));
                    }
```

I need to write the same code in Windows services temlate in Visual Studio 2010.
Can you please share on where to write the above piece of code?
When I am opening visual studio Windows services template, I am getting the below code by default where I need to fit in the above code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;

namespace PocService
 {
   public partial class PocSevice : ServiceBase
   {
       public PocSevice()
       {
          InitializeComponent();
       }


    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I think you do not understand the concept of Windows Service. Its purpose to be available 24/7. Most services execute request/reply type of processes in background and have some sort of communication mechanism to interact with "clients". One example is a database service, that processes SQL Queries from the clients. If you put your code (that just lists all the services in the system, BTW) in the OnStart method then the list will be build when the user "Starts" your service. You need to implement `Run` method to register your service. Run method should be a continuous process not like yours

Comment: @cha: Thanks for the feedback.Can you help me on that..mean time I am also checking other sites on this.